# Linux - Format ls -l command

Tags: java, linux, ls

I'm executing the `ls` command in Java using JSCH. I'm trying to format the output by separating it by comma's using the following command:

```
ls -l | sed 's/  */,/g'
```

This works for most cases, but fails for file/directory names which contain spaces. The spaces of the file name will also be split. This shouldn't happen.

Example:
[image]

The comma at `log,06-11-2018` shouldn't be there because both indices are part of the filename. Does anyone a solution to this?

Comment: If you're listing and getting files and SFTP is enabled (it usually is by default), then just use SFTP instead.

Comment: Hmm. I guess you're right. SFTP will make much things easier. I guess I'll just use that. Thanks.

Although I'm still curious if my problem can be fixed using ```sed``` command. I'll give this question 2 more days.

Comment: In the string, have you tried "\ " or doing the search with quotes

Comment: What's the actual end goal of this?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean @Joe. Can you elaborate your comment some more?

Comment: The end goal is to show all directories and files in a treeview in JavaFX @tink.

Comment: Then I’m guessing you don’t really need any information other than the names of the files, and whether they’re directories.  Consider using `ls -1p` (that’s a number one after the hyphen, not a lowercase L) instead, with no sed filter.

Comment: The regex youre using for the space character should be "\ "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is to use SFTP (thus Jsch's ChannelSftp).

See 
https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#ls-java.lang.String- for more information.